# Powershell Remove-Item Cmdlet error

Tags: powershell, directory, powershell-5.0

I'm using powershell to remove a directory with the command:

```
Remove-Item $pathAsString -Recurse -Force
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove the item at 'C:\Path' because it is in use.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item "C:\Path" -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I thought that was odd, because the directory shouldn't be in use. I can go into file explorer and delete the directory manually. I'm not really sure why this behavior is occurring. I'm fairly new to powershell, so don't understand exactly how it behaves.

My scripts interaction with the program includes:

- Creating the folder
- Downloading an MSI to the folder
- Setting a variable to represent the MSI stored in the folder. Like so:

---

```
 $MSIVariable = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where {&_.Name -eq "MSIName.msi"}
```

---

I'm assuming that something to do with the folder is within a stream of some sort, but don't know how I'd fix this issue.

**EDIT**:
Here is the code I use involving the folder:

Creating the Folder:

```
if(!(Test-Path $MSILocation))
{
    New-Item $MSILocation -ItemType directory
}
```

Downloading the MSI:

```
$webClient = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient)
$downloadLocation = Join-Path $MSILocation $MSIName
$webClient.DownloadFile($downloadURL, $downloadLocation)
```

Comment: I suspect something else in your script is locking the folder.  Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: @SamuelProut I added the code that creates the folder and downloads the MSI. Both of these functions are in a module that is imported into the main script. Right now I've found that I can delete the directory using `.delete("Path")`. So for now that is a work around, although I'm still curious about the original question.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe you were reaching the Remove-Item code before the file was finished downloading... but if that is working for you then I'm stumped.

Comment: @SamuelProut The file downloaded and installed. So I'm not entirely sure.  I found a workaround, so I'm content, but still don't understand the behavior. Thanks for the help though.